# How to touch a file and mkdir if needed in one line

Tags: linux, perl

I need to touch a file with an absolute file name such as: /opt/test/test.txt, but I'm not sure if there is /opt/test existed on the system. So the code should similar with this:

```
if (-d '/opt/test') {
    touch '/opt/test/test.txt';
} else {
    mkdir -p '/opt/test';
    touch '/opt/test/test.txt'
}
```

Is there any better way to simplify the code? I hope there is some system commands that can do the same job with only one line.

Comment: This is no valid perl code. It looks like a mixture from shell and perl code.

Comment: can't we use pipeline for this? mkdir -p '/opt/test' | touch '/opt/test/test.txt' ?

Comment: @Jango `touch` does not read anything from its standard input and `mkdir` doesn't print anything to standard out.  So no, that's just an obscure way of saying `mkdir -p /opt/test; touch /opt/test/test.txt`.

Comment: There is no guarantee of atomicity even within `mkdir -p` but if you are hellbent on doing it in one shell command, `mkdir -p /opt/test/test.txt` will create a directory in one go.  If you need a file, that won't help, of course.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In perl, using one of my favorite module: [Path::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Tiny#touchpath).

```
path("/opt/test/test.txt")->touchpath;
```

From the doc:

> Combines mkpath and touch. Creates the parent directory if it doesn't
>   exist, before touching the file.

Answer (score 23):

```
mkdir B && touch B/myfile.txt
```

Alternatively, create a function:

```
   mkfile() { 
    mkdir -p $( dirname "$1") && touch "$1" 
   }
```

Execute it with 1 arguments: filepath. Saying:

```
mkfile B/C/D/myfile.txt
```

would create the file myfile.txt in the directory B/C/D.

Comment: IMHO, would be nicer call it with one argument (`mkfile /path/to/filename`). The script (or function) could call `dirname` internally...

Comment: You can also redefine `touch`, which may not be the best idea. `echo 'touch() { mkdir -p $( dirname "$1") && /usr/bin/touch "$1" }' >> ~/.zshrc`

Comment: in some systems, `mkfile` command is already taken, consider using another name like `mkf`

Answer (score 11):

In a shell script, you can simply do:

```
mkdir -p /opt/test && touch /opt/test/test.txt
```

`mkdir -p` will not fail (and won't do anything) if the directory already exists.

In perl, use `make_path` from the [`File::Path`](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Path.html) module, then create the file however you want. `make_path` also doesn't do anything if the directory exists already, so no need to check yourself.

Answer (score 10):

I like typing very little, so I put this command into a named fn in my .profile, but I used this formulation for years before I did it:

`mkdir -p dirname/sub/dir && touch $_/filename.ext`

The variable `$_` stores the last argument to the previous command. Pretty handy to know about overall.

Answer (score 8):

I defined a `touchp` in my `~/.bash_aliases`:

```
function touchp() {
  /bin/mkdir -p "$(dirname "$1")/" && /usr/bin/touch "$1"
}
```

It silently creates the structure above the file if not present, and is perfectly safe to use when passed a single filename without any directory in front of it.

Answer (score 6):

I have this shell function in my `.zshalias` file:

```
function touch-safe {
    for f in "$@"; do
      [ -d $f:h ] || mkdir -p $f:h && command touch $f
    done
}
alias touch=touch-safe
```

If either the `test` or the `mkdir` command fail, no `touch` command is invoked.

Answer (score 4):

Perl from command line,

```
perl -MFile::Basename -MFile::Path=make_path -e'
  make_path(dirname($_)), open(F, ">>", $_) for pop;
' /opt/test/test.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Bring Python to command line.

i.e. Use [pyp](https://code.google.com/archive/p/pyp/)

```
 cat filepaths.txt | pyp "'mkdir -p '+s[0:-1]|s+'; touch '+o" | sh
```

The Pyed Piper", or pyp, is a linux command line text manipulation tool similar to awk or sed, but which uses standard python string and list methods as well as custom functions evolved to generate fast results in an intense production environment.